# How to use high charts donut charts in Angular

Tags: html, angular, highcharts, donut-chart

I would like to develop `highcharts donut charts` similar to attached image :

[image]

I have gone through multiple links but I can't find a clear solution.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Check this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-wqril

Comment: code added to codesandbox is difficult to follow.  Providing in stackblitz would be really helpful. Appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned angular,

you need the highchart npm package in your application

check the following source

https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-drilldown

**Update 1:**

To hide labels, you need to do the following

```
 dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
            }
```

check latest link https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-drilldown-m3dwq6?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Here you go,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-drilldown-m3dwq6?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: If you feel answer is helpful, feel free to upvote ans accept the answer

Comment: Facing one error.
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(47,16): error TS2322: Type '{ data: ((string | number)[] | { name: string; y: number; drilldown: string; })[]; }' i
      Property 'type' is missing in type '{ data: ((string | number)[] | { name: string; y: number; drilldown: string; })[]; }' but required in type 'SeriesXrangeOptions'.
    src/app/app.component.ts(58,18): error TS2322: Type '{ name: string; states: { hover: { enabled: boolean; }; }; id: string; data: (string | number)[][]; }' is not assignable to type 'SeriesAbandsOptions | SeriesAdOptions |

Comment: does it happen in the link I have provided?

Comment: Not able to add more comments. It doesnt happen in the link provided, but when i use it in my angular project, the error comes up.

Comment: You should ask fresh question in that case